Hardy's Asymptotic Notation
Hi everyone,
I read this page from *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Hardy and Wright, and on pg 8, I am confused by the asymptotic notation.
After reading Big O and little O notation examples, I think I understand (2) and (3). If $f=o(g)$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow k} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ and if $f \sim g$, then that means $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow k} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, where $k$ is "$\pm \infty, 0,$ or some other limiting value." Is that correct?
Also, for (1), do they mean that $f=O(g)$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow k} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<A$ where $A$ is some constant number other than 0 or 1?
Why do they choose to use $\phi$ and $g$?
Also, what does (vi) mean?
Sorry, I am kind of a beginner at number theory. Thanks!

Your first two are correct, minus the fact that the limit doesn't have to be to infinity (as they said above). The $O$ one is not; $f=O(g)$ for positive functions $f,g$ means that $f(x)/g(x)$ is bounded as $x \to \infty$ (or whatever other limit), but the ratio doesn't have to converge to anything. As for $\phi$, it's just a letter, nothing special there. The (vi) thing is referring back to the line above labeled that way to point to how they're going to be writing seemingly weird things like that again in the future.

No, your definitions are less general. As the book says, the notation can be used not only when $x \to \infty$, but also when $x \to 0$ or any other limit.

Thanks for the tips! I have updated my OP with the corrected limit for x for the equations.
